# Parse json use JsonOjbect vs map into entity with GSon

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm looking for the right way to parse json use GSon library. Up to now, I have known 2 ways to do this:
Assume I have a json string like this:

```
 {
   'Events' : [{
       'name' : 'exp',
       'date' : '10-10-2010',
       'tags' : ["tag 1", "tag2", "tag3"]
    },...more events...],
       'Contacts' : [{
       'name' : 'John Smith',
       'date' : '10-10-2010',
       'tags' : ["tag 1", "tag2", "tag3"]
    },...more contacts...],
 }
```

1. Use JSonOjbect to get field by its name:

   ```
   JsonElement jelement = new JsonParser().parse(jsonLine);
   JsonObject  jobject = jelement.getAsJsonObject();
   jobject = jobject.getAsJsonArray("Events");
   JsonArray jarray = jobject.getAsJsonArray("Contacts");
   jobject = jarray.get(0).getAsJsonObject();
   ```
2. Use GSon to map into entity

   ```
   public class Container{
      List<Event> Events;
       List<Contact> Contacts;
   }

   Container c = new GSon().fromJSon(jsonString,Container.class);
   ```

Could you tell me when I should use the first way or the second?
I have a web service could return many kinds of complex json string, and I need get data from this. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [benchmarks](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-performance), the first approach (`GSON_DOM`) is faster. This is likely because with the DOM approach you are only deserializing part of the JSON string. If you wanted even more performance you could switch to the `GSON_STREAM` approach which seems to do best in the benchmarks.

Practically, the second approach makes for simpler code. I would use probably use that approach first and then switch to one of the other methods if I find that JSON deserialization is taking a significant amount of time.

Comment: Pardon me, could you explain `GSON_DOM` and `GSON_STREAM` ? I don't know what they are. Are there the first and second in my question?

Comment: Your first approach is `GSON_DOM` and your second approach is `GSON_BIND`.

Comment: Thanks, I got it. Let me try your way.